# ArrayAdapter getView(): what I see, in the ListView, does not match what is under the data linked to the adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I all,
I have a problem that does not allow me to show an icon at a row in the ListView, only when one data of the row matches a parameter that comes from another source. In my exmple i will force this parameter as static.

I have this code that basically works well:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

Context context;
List<User> items;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<User> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

public int getCount() {
    return this.items.size();
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView rubrPhoto;
    TextView rubrNick;
    TextView rubrEmail;
    ImageView provaImg;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("CustomListViewAdapter", "position = "+position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    User user = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rubrica_list_view, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.rubrPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rubrPhoto);
        holder.rubrNick = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rubrNick);
        holder.rubrEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rubrEmail);
        holder.provaImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rubrNewMess);

        //extra logic
        String email = user.getEmail();
        Log.d("CustomListViewAdapter", "FIRST TIME CREATED---> "+email);
        if(email.equals("giada@email.com")){
            Log.d("CustomListViewAdapter", "##############IN THE IF ... ");
            holder.provaImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        //end

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        //extra logic
        Log.d("CustomListViewAdapter", "CACHED---> email user ---->"+user.getEmail());
        CharSequence email = user.getEmail();

        if(email.equals("giada@email.com")){
            Log.d("CustomListViewAdapter", "IN THE IF.. ");
            holder.provaImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    //end
    }
    holder.rubrPhoto.setImageResource(user.getPhoto());
    holder.rubrNick.setText(user.getNick());
    holder.rubrEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
    holder.provaImg.setImageResource(user.getNewMess());

    return convertView;
}
```

Initially all the holder.provaImg have the VISIBILITY set to GONE by the XML layout. However it seems that the caching mechanism the Adapter does not work well, at least from what I have to do.

The code

```
User user = getItem (position);
```

and

```
String email = user.getEmail ();
```

are correct and correspond with what I see. Initially only the right icon is shown but when i start scrolling something crash and getView sets the visibility of the icon in a wrong row , as if the caching mechanism works differently from the logic.

At the end **getView()** sets the visibility of icons in rows where the email does not match.

Maybe I'm close to the solution but an help will save definitely my life.
Thank you very much.

Comment: try adding else statement to your if and inside the else set the visibility back to invisible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the visibility of the *provaImg* `ImageView` incorrectly. It should be like this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
//...
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
holder.rubrPhoto.setImageResource(user.getPhoto());
holder.rubrNick.setText(user.getNick());
holder.rubrEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
holder.provaImg.setImageResource(user.getNewMess());
CharSequence email = user.getEmail();
// if the email is the right one, show the ImageView
if(email.equals("giada@email.com")){
    Log.d("CustomListViewAdapter", "##############IN THE IF ... ");
    holder.provaImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    // hide the ImageView so we don't end up with row problems
    // as the convertView could be non-null and the row from where that convertView
    // is coming could have the ImageView set to visible we need to make sure
    // we revert the row to the correct state
    holder.provaImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // or GONE
}
```

Comment: Oh yesss, now it goes smoothly. Thanks guy!!